# Cannot debug over VPN - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, debugging, virtual-machine, visual-studio-debugging

I have no trouble debugging from [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010) when I go to work and wire into the LAN.

However, when I telecommute over the corporate [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network), I cannot debug, because when I try to debug, the monitor correctly shows a status of <datetime>  CONNECTED, but Visual Studio 2010 comes back with the "Unable to connect ...The remote computer cannot connect back to this computer" message.

There is no change in procedure between debugging from home or debugging from work; it simply won't work over the VPN...

The remote machine is my VM running on corporate servers someplace. I can ping my developer machine from the remote virtual machine, and I'm using Windows authentication mode. Both machines are Windows 7 64-bit.

The application I wrote is deployed using the full-trust mode of [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce).

Why?

Comment: This is a networking issue, not a programming issue. Ask your network administrator; they may be blocking some ports / protocols VS uses for remote debugging.

Comment: Ondrej: I did - the firewall team said that everything is wide open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what was wrong:

Our corporate firewall allows remote clients to come in via **SSLVPN** and see everything at the corporation. What our firewall does not have is the **reverse rule** which allows computers already within the firewall to see remote clients as soon as they log in.

Therefore, the machine being debugged, which was running MSVSMON.EXE, could not see the machine running the Visual Studio 2010 debugger.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to answer your own question! I'm looking to get work to enable VPN-based development, do you have any resources to suggest to get started?

Comment: Are you trying to motivate your employer to let your team telecommute?